# ASP.NET Session State Timeout Problem

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

I am trying to detect a session state timeout in my asp.net application and am unable to do so. I have a base class that derives from System.Web.UI.Page as follows:-

```
public class BasePageSessionExpire : Page
{
    override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e); 
        if (Context.Session != null)
        {                
            if (Session.IsNewSession)
            {                    
                string szCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != szCookieHeader) && (szCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") > 0))
                {
                    Session.Abandon();
                    Response.Redirect("~/SessionExpired.aspx",true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the pages I need session state checking on derive from this base class instead of "System.Web.UI.Page". Also, all these pages have EnableSessionState="True". I have a blank Session_Start() method in my global.asax file if that is relevant at all.

For some reason after the first request, the "Session.IsNewSession" property is always false. It is true only for the first request and then is always false. I have my timeout set to 1 minute. The session never seems to timeout. What am I missing here ?

Also I have implemented a state server in SQL Server 2008. This is not an in-proc session state implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have Session_start event in global.asax file, after the session expires, Session_start fired again. that means session Id is already created and so oninit event IsNewSessionId would return false because session Id is already created.

So removing the Session_Start event will work.

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.Net session is started on the user's first request to a server.  This is the only time that `IsNewSession` will be true.

Calling Session.Abandon() removes the current session, and then if you redirect the user to the SessionExpired page, that will start a new session.

I'm not sure why the timeout would not be firing.  Have you put code in the Global.asax Session_End event to verify that sessions aren't ending?

Comment: So you are saying that the IsNewSession will always be false after the first request ? So essentially even if the session did timeout, the code above wouldn't work, because IsNewSession would always be false and the code would never get a chance to go in and execute "Session.Abandon" when the session does in fact timeout ?

Comment: IsNewSession will only be true for the HttpRequest that caused a new session object to be created.  The first request to the server after a timeout should do this I believe.

Comment: Also I have implemented a state server in SQL Server 2008. This is not an in-proc session state implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In your application , If no Session_Start event, Then each time `IsNewSession` would return true for each postback unless until you store some value in session.

Once you store some value in session, the `IsNewSession` would return false next time even many post back.

Once session expires, `IsNewSession` would return true till no session stores.